# Tomcat binary distribution zip as maven artifact

Tags: tomcat, maven

Is there a publicly available maven repository that hosts the Apache Tomcat binary distribution ZIPs as maven artifacts (I mean the file that can be downloaded via http://tomcat.apache.org, e.g. http://mirror.serversupportforum.de/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.28/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.28.zip)?

Currently I download these distribution zips manually and put them into my Nexus repo, but I'd find it more elegant if there was such a repo that I just could add to my POMs. Does anybody else need the Tomcat distribution ZIPs within their maven build, how do you cope with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't such a repository or artifact.

I was looking into this a while ago because we have a standard Tomcat which we pre-configure and ship along with our product.

We ended up downloading the Tomcat zip from the official site (via Maven) and then applying the required changes and then pushing them over to our Nexus.

Here's more or less how we do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.28-ourbranding-1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Pre-Configured Tomcat</name>

    <properties>
        <version.tomcat>7.0.28</version.tomcat>
        <tomcat.archive.file>${project.build.directory}/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}.zip</tomcat.archive.file>
    </properties>

    <build>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Re-packaging ${tomcat.archive.file}..." />

                                <unzip src="${basedir}/src/main/lib/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}.zip" dest="${project.build.directory}" />

                                <move file="${project.build.directory}/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}" tofile="${project.build.directory}/tomcat" />

                                <!-- Remove the default webapps -->
                                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/tomcat/webapps/docs" />
                                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/tomcat/webapps/manager" />
                                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/tomcat/webapps/host-manager" />
                                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/tomcat/webapps/examples" />

                                <!-- Patch the bin/catalina* scripts to include some of our jars in the classpath -->

                                <!-- ... Some more magic goes on here ... -->
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${tomcat.archive.file}</file>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what we do, too. What I'd like better is just to change the tomcat dependency version (e.g. when a new release was published), and maven automatically retrieves it.

Comment: Okay, that's nearly the same way we do it. But instead of committing the original tomcat.zip into the version control system, we keep it in our nexus. When I want to use a new tomcat release, I download it and manually upload it into our Nexus, so I can refer to it as a real dependency from the maven build.

Comment: I'm sure this answer was true when it was given, but tomcat is now available in Maven Central, per the other answer. This answer still says at the top "No, there isn't such a repository or artifact."

Answer (score 39):

Distributions of Tomcat 7.0.35 and higher are in Maven Central under `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat` with type `zip` or `tar.gz`.

Comment: The accepted answer is now outdated and this is the valid one.

Comment: But to be fair, these zips are just the 'pure' release without the (for example) Windows-specific `tcnative` and `commons-deamon` binaries

Answer (score 2):

The only location i know for sure is:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/

which can be used via Maven download...

Comment: But that's no maven repo, no pom's etc. I don't think one can add this  to Nexus as proxy repo.

Comment: Yes it's not repository. But you can use wagon plugin to download it during a Maven build.